# Why does it show same value for every image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying Image Recognition using simple numbers. But my problem is every time I run with different digit image, it shows the same value instead of the displayed image.

I've tried it with different digits and also checked the code many times at every function.

```
#VKA
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import time
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter


def createExamples():
    numberArrayExamples = open('numArEx.txt','a')
    numbersWeHave = range(0,10)
    versionsWeHave = range(1,10)

    for eachNum in numbersWeHave:
        for eachver in versionsWeHave:
            #print(str(eachNum)+'.'+str(eachver))
            imgFilePath = 'images/numbers/'+str(eachNum)+'.'+str(eachver)+'.png'
            #print(imgFilePath)
            ei = Image.open(imgFilePath)
            eiar = np.array(ei)
            # print(eiar)
            eiar1 = str(eiar.tolist())
            # print(eiar1)

            lineToWrite = str(eachNum)+'::'+eiar1+'\n'
            #print(lineToWrite)
            numberArrayExamples.write(lineToWrite)

def threshold(imgarray):
    balanceAR = []
    newAR = imgarray

    for eachrow in imgarray:
        for eachpix in eachrow:
            avgNum = reduce(lambda x, y : x + y,
                                eachpix[:3])/len(eachpix[:3])
            balanceAR.append(avgNum)
    #print(balanceAR)
    balance = reduce(lambda x, y : x + y, balanceAR)/len(balanceAR)
    #print(balance)
    for eachrow in newAR:
        for eachpix in eachrow:
            if reduce(lambda x, y :
                x + y, eachpix[:3])/len(eachpix[:3]) > balance:
                eachpix[0] = 255
                eachpix[1] = 255
                eachpix[2] = 255
                eachpix[3] = 255
            else:
                eachpix[0] = 0
                eachpix[1] = 0
                eachpix[2] = 0
                eachpix[3] = 255

    return newAR

def whatNumIsThis(filepath):
    matchedAr = []
    loadExamps = open("numArEx.txt",'r').read()
    loadExamps = loadExamps.split('\n')

    i = Image.open(filepath)
    iar = np.array(i)
    iarl = iar.tolist()
    threshold(iar)
    inQuestion = str(iarl)

    for eachExample in loadExamps:
        if len(eachExample) > 3:
            #print(len(eachExample))
            splitEx = eachExample.split('::')
            #print(splitEx)
            currentNum = splitEx[0]
            #print(currentNum)
            currentAr = splitEx[1]
            #print(currentAr)
            eachPixEx = currentAr.split('],')
            #print(eachPixEx)
            eachPixInQ = inQuestion.split('],')
            # print(eachPixInQ)

            x=0
            #print(eachPixEx)
            while x < len(eachPixEx):
                if eachPixEx[x] == eachPixInQ[x]:
                    matchedAr.append(int(currentNum))

                x += 1


    print(matchedAr)
    x = Counter(matchedAr)
    print(x)



    graphX = []
    graphY = []

    for eachThing in x:
     #   print(eachThing)
        graphX.append(eachThing)
      #  print(x[eachThing])
        graphY.append(x[eachThing])



    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4),(0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=4)
    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4),(1,0), rowspan=3, colspan=4)

    ax1.imshow(iar)
    ax2.bar(graphX,graphY, align='center')
    plt.ylim(400)

    xloc = plt.MaxNLocator(12)
    #print(xloc)
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(xloc)

    #plt.show()'''
#createExamples()
whatNumIsThis('images/test.png')
```

The expected output should be like if the test image is 3, it should display the counter value with 3 as the matched value with highest accuracy rate. But the problem here is everytime with different inputs, it displays 4 as output for every number image...

For further detailed description refer following link...

https://pythonprogramming.net/image-recognition-python/